# MikTex Download Failure - toptesi.tar.lzma

Tags: miktex

I try to install Complete MiKTeX 2.9 But there is this:

Error: The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification:

C:...\mikTex\toptesi.tar.lzma

There is the same with the basic version.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: I have the same problem.  It seems that it occurs no matter which mirror I choose.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug of this packed file. Fixed on the same day this question was migated from StackOverflow, cf. [error in download of complete installation 32 bit](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2298/).